# Pandas Dataframe, sum single value grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have searched for this answer but cannot find something which will work. I want to sum a column `keyword_visibility` and group it by three columns `category`, `trend_month`, `trend_year`.

The result would be in the same dataframe and would be called `sum_keyword_visibility_by_category`.

What I have tried includes:

```
df_market_share['sum_keyword_visibility_by_category'] = df_market_share.groupby(['category', 'trend_month', 'trend_year'])['keyword_visibility'].sum()
```

and

```
df_market_share['sum_keyword_visibility_by_category'] = df_market_share["keyword_visibility"].groupby(df_market_share["category"], ["trend_month" ]).transform("sum")
```

Error I am getting for the first attempt is this `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` and for the second attempt this `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` any help is much appreciated

Comment: Add some example data and expected output based on your example data, so we can visually see what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are grouping values. you are trying to insert the result of a groupby and summation into the normal indexes of your data frame.
Which means that you are trying to insert a smaller set of values into the new column.

Check this link:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

If you want to insert the results into your dataframe you can locate the corresponding values and insert the results with df.loc

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to use transform. The following example groups by two columns, but it should be clear how to extend to three:

```
data = [     
['A', 'C', 1 ],          
['A', 'D', 2 ],        
['A', 'C', 2 ],        
['B', 'C', 3 ],       
['B', 'D', 4],
['B', 'C', 4]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2',  'col_to_sum'])
df['summed_col']  = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col_to_sum.transform('sum')
df
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2   col_to_sum  summed_col
0   A   C       1           3
1   A   D       2           2
2   A   C       2           3
3   B   C       3           7
4   B   D       4           4
5   B   C       4           7
```